Azure container app job 'no space left on device' - how to get more space?
I am running a container app job which pulls some git repos and scans the code of the repos.
However, in my log i can see that i keep getting the error that there is no space left on the device.
And i don't understand how i can get more space?
I save each repo in a temp folder, scan the repo, and then i delete the temp folder before moving on to the next repo, like so:
foreach repo:
    mkdir tmp
    cd tmp
    .. git clone --depth 1 $reponame
    .. scan repo
    cd ..
    rm tmp -rf

This prevents me from accumulating a lot of data on the device. However, i still run out of space sooner or later.
I also use git clone --depth 1 to only pull a shallow clone.
I suspect that some of the repos i am pulling are larger than the space there is on my azure container app job container, so i would like to increase the space on the container but cannot figure out how.
I am using a consumption plan and the container i use has 4 cpu cores and 8Gi memory.
I have also tried to split up the work into multiple containers but i still encounter the issue.

Hi have you tried the below solution which I have posted.


I have also tried to split up the work into multiple containers but i still encounter the issue.

Azure Container Instances (ACI) allow you to specify a larger disk size. You can increase the storage for the container instance by using the Azure Files or Managed Disk option to mount additional storage.

Configure additional storage in the YAML file for ACI:

apiVersion: 2021-10-01
location: eastus
properties:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    properties:
      image: myimage:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 4.0
          memoryInGB: 8.0
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /mnt/volume1
        name: volume1
  volumes:
  - name: volume1
    azureFile:
      sharename: sharename
      storageAccountName: storageAccountName
      storageAccountKey: storageAccountKey


Sometimes lingering files or caches can take up more space than expected. To cleanup use the below cmd.

rm -rf tmp/*


Check the below .sh file script it provides with logging to monitor disk usage before and after each repository operation. The result will show how much space is being used at each step.

repos=("repo1" "repo2" "repo3") # Add your repositories here

for reponame in "${repos[@]}"; do
    echo "Processing $reponame"

    echo "Before cloning:"
    df -h
    du -sh *

    # Create tmp directory and clone the repository
    mkdir tmp
    cd tmp
    git clone --depth 1 $reponame

    echo "After cloning:"
    df -h
    du -sh *

    # Placeholder for your scanning operation
    echo "Scanning $reponame..."
    # scan repo

    cd ..
    rm -rf tmp

    echo "After cleanup:"
    df -h
    du -sh *
done

Cloning repo1:

Scanning:

After cleanup:


is it the same for aca?

When working with Azure Container Apps (ACA), monitoring disk usage and cleanup remain similar, though the actual implementation details and how you interact with the container might differ slightly.

@NaveenSharma I am not the poster
